# Degree of a separable extension of a Dedekind ring's quotient field

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain, separable-extension

I'm studying "Algebraic number theory" written by S. Lang. In proposition 21 of chapter 1.7 it says if $A$ is a Dedekind ring and $K$ its quotient field, for a separable extension $L/K$, $[L:K]=\sum_{P|p} e_P f_P$ where $p$ is a prime ideal in $A$ and $e_P, f_P$ are ramification indexes and residue class degrees.

My problem is a part of its proof; It says if $B$ is $A$'s integral closure in $L$ then $B/pB$ is an $A/p$-vector space of dimension $[L:K]$. I don't see why this holds. I tried to show if $a_1,...,a_n$ are basis of $L$ as a $K$-vector space then $a_i$s are integral over $A$ hence a generator for $B$ as an $A$-module so that from $[B/pB:A/p]=[B:A]$ the result can be obtained. But the leading coefficient wouldn't remain unity over $A$

Comment: By clearing denominators, you may assume that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ lie in $B$, i.e. are integral over $A$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin I'm really sorry for still not understanding, you mean clearing denominators in their minimal polynomials over $K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that we need to look at $A_p=(A-p)^{-1}A$ which is a PID (and DVR). The separability of $L/K$ gives that $A_p B$ is a finitely generated $A_p$-module

> (I don't recall the exact argument here, I think it is based on that $L\cong K[x]/(f)$ with $f\in A_p[x]_{monic}$ and $0\ne Disc(f)=\det(Tr(x^i x^j))$ so we'd get $\sum_{i=0}^{[L:K]-1} x^i A_p \subset A_p B\subset \frac1{Disc(f)} \sum_{i=0}^{[L:K]-1} x^i A_p$).

Then we use a general linear algebra theorem that finitely generated $R$-modules are free whenever they are contained in a $Frac(R)$-vector space and $R$ is a PID.

Since $K B = L$ is a $[L:K]$-dimensional $K$-vector space it gives that $A_pB$ is a free $A_p$-module of rank $[L:K]$, so that $[B/pB:A/pA]=[A_pB/pA_pB:A_p/pA_p]=[L:K]$.

Comment: Keith Conrad will certainly come to add better insights

Comment: The OP had omitted an essential point from the first sentence of Lang's proof, which you point out: we can localize $A$ and $B$ at the prime ideal downstairs in order to put ourselves in the position of $A$ being a DVR, and thus a PID. (Localizing commutes with integral closures, so $B$ localized at the prime downstairs is the integral closure of $A$ localized at that prime ideal.) Then $B$ is a free $A$-module of rank $[L:K]$ by exactly the same argument as the ring of integers of a number field being a free $\mathbf Z$-module, using discriminants in the same way you have done here.

Comment: It's also important that localizing at the prime ideal downstairs doesn't affect the values of the ramification indices or residue field degrees at the prime ideals lying over it upstairs. (I have avoided using notation for the prime ideals because I dislike the OP's decision to write $p$ and $P$ instead of $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak P$ as in Lang.)